# How to escape special characters while doing XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml

One of my element in an xml has a value like

```
<item name="abc_def&#x13;&gt;" />
```

The actual value pulled from the data source is `"abc_def!!>"`. I have no control over this data source and this cannot be changed.

I wanted to know how do I escape these characters when xml serialization is taking place. I have tried a couple of things, but they didnt work.

I tried all methods explained [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)

What is the correct way to escape these characters ? The end output is an api which our clients hit using their browsers and because of this issue, the xml parsing in browser is breaking.

[image]

Comment: Your data is not xml. The value of `&#x13;` is unacceptable in xml. Try using a html parser. Or pre-replace the value of `&#x13;` to valid with `string.Replace`.

Comment: &#x13; is actually a character with hex value 19, or the ASCII control code DC3. Why wouldn't that be valid?

Comment: The [XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) says the only valid control chars are whitespace, but in the same line it says _any Unicode character_, so I don't know how seriously we should take that.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your strings look like that one, you can do something like this:

```
string input = "abc_def&#x13;&gt;";
input = input.Replace("&#x13;", "!!");
string output = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
```

Comment: `!!` is not correct, it's just an attempt of the system to make the U+0013 visible. In the original IBM character set, \x13 looked like `‼`,so that's what is displayed there. `‼` is now U+203C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(stringToEncode);
```

Of course when you later decode that you use:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(stringToDecode);
```

This is for UWP, namespace may vary depending on what framework you use.